# jasper page numbering for nultiple reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

we are generating jasper batch reports, where group of dynamic reports of various sizes needs to be generated. by sizes i mean a report can be 2 pages or 3 pages or any number of pages based on the content.

since we are generating these reports in a bulk. the numbering has been a problem. after one report is generated the page number should of the next report should come back to 1. but jasper is treating as a contagious reports and giving undesired page numbers.

how to identify that generation one document has ended and set the next documents page number to initial value.

need some suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: the question heading is "jasper page numbering for mulitple reports"

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood the question. Let's say, there are 3 reports of 5 pages each. Are you saying that after the completion of report 1, the report 2 starts with the page number as 6?

Comment: yes, you are right. i want the report 2 to be starting with 1 and also report 3 and so on

Comment: As long as you have separate jrxmls for the reports, the page numbers should work fine. The page numbers can be reset only while working with 'group' in a report.
 <group name="Group Name" isResetPageNumber="true"/>